# Memory error exceeds the maximum page size in Excel when connecting to ssas

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, cube, olap-cube

When trying to connect to ssas cube (multidimensional) through Excel we get the error below:

> We couldn't get data from the external source. Here's the error message we got:
>
> Memory error : A record (65569 bytes) was encountered that exceeds the maximum page size of the storage object (65528 bytes)

I have searched about the issue but didn't find anything helpful so decided  to truncate every measure group and delete data from all dimensions and process each time to see where is the error source but this takes a long time. Has anyone before face this situation? Any help would be much appreciated.